# How to refresh auth tokens with react-native-auth0?

Tags: react-native, auth0

I'm implementing authentication with `react-native-auth0` and was looking for a way how to obtain `refreshToken` and how to use it to get new `accessToken` and `idToken` tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Basically I used `auth0.passwordRealm` for implementing login with email/password:

```js
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';
...
const config = {
    username: email,
    password: password,
    realm: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
    scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
    audience: 'https://' + Auth0Config.domain + '/userinfo',
};
const credentials = await auth0.auth.passwordRealm(config);
```

Auth0 doesn't send you `refreshToken` until you put `offline_access` into scope prop. In my case accessToken lives 24 hours which is mentioned in `expiresIn` prop of credentials. And now we can use refreshToken for requesting new tokens.

```js
const newCredentials = await auth0.auth.refreshToken({
  refreshToken: credentials.refreshToken,
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
});
```

`newCredentials` now contains updated `accessToken` and `idToken`. You will also get new `refreshToken` if you have `Refresh Token Rotation` enabled in Auth0 dashboard.